# Provide multiple encodings of same audio rendition in HLS

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I would like to stream video with adaptive streaming using HLS.

Given an appropriate device and sufficient bandwidth, the video should be presented in HD and with 5.1 sound.

On devices that have lower bandwidth or no need for 5.1 sound, a lower resolution and stereo sound should be used.

Right now, my master playlist looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="AUDIO",NAME="en 5.1",LANGUAGE="en",URI="audio/en_5.1.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="AUDIO",NAME="en 2.0",LANGUAGE="en",URI="audio/en_2.0.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="AUDIO",NAME="de 5.1",LANGUAGE="de",URI="audio/de_5.1.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="AUDIO",NAME="de 2.0",LANGUAGE="de",URI="audio/de_2.0.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="AUDIO",NAME="es 2.0",LANGUAGE="es",URI="audio/es_2.0.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=944846,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=933666,CODECS="avc1.64001E,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=768x328,AUDIO="AUDIO"
video_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1269710,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1252915,CODECS="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1024x436,AUDIO="AUDIO"
video_1.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2003662,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1976439,CODECS="avc1.640020,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1600x682,AUDIO="AUDIO"
video_2.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2954190,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2911727,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x818,AUDIO="AUDIO"
video_3.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=716238,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=709068,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=512x218,AUDIO="AUDIO"
video_4.m3u8
```

However, this obviously doesn't yield the correct result:

Each of those 5 audio tracks is presented to the user as an individual rendition.

However, only 3 renditions should be presented: "en,de,es"

Selection between 5.1 and 2.0 should be automatic.

Is there any way to achieve this with HLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video stream is a variant stream. We can provide different audio encodings by defining two audio groups with different members which have the same attributes except channels, and then referring to those two different groups from specific variants:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-VERSION:6

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_l",CHANNELS="2",NAME="Audio 0",URI="audio_0l.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_l",CHANNELS="2",NAME="Audio 1",URI="audio_1l.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_l",CHANNELS="2",NAME="Audio 2",URI="audio_2l.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_h",CHANNELS="6",NAME="Audio 0",URI="audio_0h.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_h",CHANNELS="6",NAME="Audio 1",URI="audio_1h.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_h",CHANNELS="2",NAME="Audio 2",URI="audio_2h.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1637313,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1609092,CODECS="avc1.640020,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1600x682,AUDIO="audio_l"
video_3.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=376055,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=370421,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=512x218,AUDIO="audio_l"
video_0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=597555,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=588987,CODECS="avc1.64001E,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=768x328,AUDIO="audio_l"
video_1.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=916599,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=900940,CODECS="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1024x436,AUDIO="audio_l"
video_2.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2757067,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2715497,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x818,AUDIO="audio_h"
video_4.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=4203897,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=4173401,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x818,AUDIO="audio_h"
video_5.m3u8
```

This way, when playback switches to a higher video resolution, it will also switch to surround sound if it is available for the given rendition.

Obviously it is not perfect to be combining the switching of video resolution with switching of audio channel count, but this is the best I could come up with for HLS.

Note we are including "Audio 2" which only is available in stereo in the "audio_h" group too, as the groups need to have identical members.